# Problems installing Symfony

Tags: symfony1, mamp

Apologies if I seem confused – I've been working on this for days, getting into an ever deeper hole!

I have MAMP PRO running on OS X Lion. I started to install Symfony 2 using [skripted instructions](http://skripted.ruhoh.com/2012/06/16/setting-up-symfony-2-on-mac-os-x-lion-with-mamp/). There were some problems as I was using MAMP PRO, but Symfony responded with directions directed to my version.

Then I discovered my MAMP PRO was out of date, and D/Led the newest version (2.1.1). But it has a newer version of PHP (5.4.4). I accounted for that, and I'm sure I copied the `intl.so` extension to the right spot. Then I copied the correct `php.ini` file to the desktop, and made changes in it.

But now, I can't 'move the file back to it’s original directory.' It simply won't go!! Even removing the installed file makes no difference: the file I copy to the directory is the original version of the file (`/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini`). Grrrr.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions problem. Try [launching Finder as root](http://www.mikesel.info/launch-finder-as-root/) and then moving the php.ini file back where it belongs.